# Why does Java 8 provide a LongAccumulator but not an IntAccumulator?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, compare-and-swap, atomicinteger

Currently, my program makes heavy use of `AtomicInteger`s in order to keep track of running maximums of ints that are reported in parallel.

After reading about Java 8's new `LongAccumulator`s, I had hoped to use an `IntAccumulator` with `max` as the accumulator function in order to accomplish my desired behavior with less thread contention. However it doesn't seem to exist.

Is there some reason that an `IntAccumulator` wouldn't make sense?  It seems plausible to me that there could be low level instructions that make an `IntAdder` unnecessary, but an `IntAccumulator` could represent more behaviors than can be captured by a low level instruction.

(If it's relevant at all, I intend to use these from Scala code)

Comment: Perhaps they didn't deem it useful to have `Int` versions of the classes. You don't see a `ShortAccumulator` or `ShortAdder` either.

Comment: Well, __do__ you really need it? Why not just use `Long::max` instead as in `LongAccumulator accumulator = new LongAccumulator(Long::max, 0);`? Then use it with regular integers like `accumulator.accumulate(10);`. As a side note, I dug through a mailthread (http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-January/013388.html), but no mention about the design decision.

Comment: @Magnilex I agree that it's not strictly necessary, but I had been hoping to not incur a performance penalty for switching to Longs.

Comment: I don't believe there would be a performance difference at the instruction level or a memory savings by using ints instead. I think that the shared nature of the counters, object alignment, cache block size, etc. would make the 32-bit and 64-bit equivalent on x86-64.